# Can a Accumulating snapshot table has multiple dates in it?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, star-schema, datamart

I am trying to make sense of dimension modeling. While reading a dimension modeling book, I have created a star schema.

The fact table is a Accumulating snapshot table and it has multiple date columns which are linked to a date dimension using a surrogate key.

```
FactApplicants
{
            Interview_No_Show_Date_Key (FK)
            Cancel_Date_Key  (FK)
            Interviewed_Date_Key (FK) 
.  .... 
            Applicant_Key(FK)
            InquiryCount int
}

DimDate
{
         Date_Key (PK, int),
         FullDateUSA (char(10))
         Date (datetime)

}
```

I do have a well defined process for which i am trying to make this star schema for. I have a date field in the fact table for each of this step as I need to prepare funnel like report and activity reports. So the question really is

Is this correct? can a fact table refer to same date dimension table multiple times?

The examples I am seeing all over the internet seems to indicate this is correct but i am having hard time making it work with Pentaho reporting. so I am not sure if its a design problem or its something i am not doing correctly in Pentaho

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct to refer to the date dimension multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a fact can refer to the same dimension multiple times. However, given only what I see in your example, I am not sure why you need the date dimension. The date in applicants is just a date and can be used as an attribute without referring to a separate date dimension. It's just the attribute "date". You would need a separate date dimension if, for example, (1) you want to ensure that only valid dates are used, or (2) you want to elevate date to a full calendar in which other attributes are used to describe a date, such as day of the week, weekday/weekend, holiday, etc. or (3) you want to rollup date to other levels, such as week, month, year.